# Volatile EquivalenceClass has no sortref

Tags: postgresql

I'm running:
PostgreSQL 9.0.3  (Last Debian stable)

This query:

> SELECT * FROM sis.thread_categories
>   stc, sis.threads st WHERE
>   st.id_thread_categories=stc.id

=> throws:

> ERROR: volatile EquivalenceClass has
>   no sortref State SQL: XX000

Same problem occured when I've tried it using JOIN. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have a corrupted database, that is not supposed to happen. From [`backend/optimizer/path/pathkeys.c`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/pathkeys_8c-source.html#l00618) in the PostgreSQL source:

```
List *
convert_subquery_pathkeys(PlannerInfo *root, RelOptInfo *rel,
                                                  List *subquery_pathkeys)
{
    /*...*/
            if (sub_eclass->ec_sortref == 0)        /* can't happen */
                elog(ERROR, "volatile EquivalenceClass has no sortref");
```

That error message shows up in two other places in the source but the triggering condition, `ec_sortref == 0`, is the same and the same "can't happen" comments appears in all three places.

So either your database is corrupt or you have found a bug in PostgreSQL.